# Is it possible to implement SystemTrayIcon functionality in Qt Quick application

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I am writing a QtQuick desktop application. I use both c++ (for functionality) and QML (for UI) in it. 
I use QQuickView to show the interface written in QML.

I want this application to reside in System Tray when minimised.

I mean a functionality similar to this example. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/desktop-systray.html . 
I am trying to implement this feature but could not find a way to do this in my Qt Quick application.

Here is my main.cpp code:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQmlFileSelector>
#include <QQuickView>
#include "myapp.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc,argv);
    app.setApplicationName(QFileInfo(app.applicationFilePath()).baseName());
    QDir::setCurrent(qApp->applicationDirPath());

    MyApp myappObject;

    QQuickView view;

    view.connect(view.engine(), SIGNAL(quit()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myappObject", &myappObject);
    new QQmlFileSelector(view.engine(), &view);

    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:///myapp.qml"));

    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);   
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Please help by providing any hint/pointers to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this only with QML, or C++/Qt can be used ?

Comment: Hi BlueMagma, C++/Qt can be used. My UI is created using QML and I launch this from Qt main.cpp file. I have just updated my main.cpp file code in my question.

Answer (score 14):

I was facing the same challenge today and ended up using the following solution within main(). Works great for me when using Qt 5.3. You should of course implement a better way to check whether the first root object is your application window object or not.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QAction>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QSystemTrayIcon>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    if (!QSystemTrayIcon::isSystemTrayAvailable()) {
        QMessageBox::critical(0, QObject::tr("Systray"),
                                 QObject::tr("I couldn't detect any system tray "
                                             "on this system."));
        return 1;
    }
    QApplication::setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(false);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    QObject *root = 0;
    if (engine.rootObjects().size() > 0)
    {
        root = engine.rootObjects().at(0);

        QAction *minimizeAction = new QAction(QObject::tr("Mi&nimize"), root);
        root->connect(minimizeAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), root, SLOT(hide()));
        QAction *maximizeAction = new QAction(QObject::tr("Ma&ximize"), root);
        root->connect(maximizeAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), root, SLOT(showMaximized()));
        QAction *restoreAction = new QAction(QObject::tr("&Restore"), root);
        root->connect(restoreAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), root, SLOT(showNormal()));
        QAction *quitAction = new QAction(QObject::tr("&Quit"), root);
        root->connect(quitAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), qApp, SLOT(quit()));

        QMenu *trayIconMenu = new QMenu();
        trayIconMenu->addAction(minimizeAction);
        trayIconMenu->addAction(maximizeAction);
        trayIconMenu->addAction(restoreAction);
        trayIconMenu->addSeparator();
        trayIconMenu->addAction(quitAction);

        QSystemTrayIcon *trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(root);
        trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
        trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(":/resources/DatagnanLogoColor.png"));
        trayIcon->show();
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Cons: it causes Qt5Widgets module dependency. Seems that it is not possible to use system tray from plain qml.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the Windos class (window.cpp/window.h) from systray example to your project, port it to Qt5 if necessary and open both from your main file:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ...
    QQuickView view;
    // ... 
    view.show();

    Window window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Hi Sion Wart, where can i take window.cpp & window.h files ?

Comment: I understand you meant the windows.cpp /windows.h files from systray example. I tried them and made it work. But both Windows (one originating from Window.cpp & the qml based window created by QML (via QQuickView) appear. It doesnt solve my requirement. How to integarate them. If possible pls give more details.

Comment: You'll now need to integrate your functionality in C++. Modify the `Window` class to your needs, and start to send signals between your main program and `Window`, for example to show/hide/modify the icon.